# Is putting a User's ID on the page a security risk?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

We are using Asp.net MVC with AngularJS. We want to put the user's ID in some static data on the page. Don't worry we have secured all of out MVC API controllers using [Authorize] attribute. However is it really a risk putting the user's ID on a page Someone asked me and I couldn't really think why not although I still didn't think it would be a good idea.

Comment: Usually, I use GUIDs instead of integers when I have to use the user IDs in public places (URL, postback values, ...)

Comment: It depends what you do with that user id. Do you use it directly to do something on DB? Then yes, it's unsafe because a malicious authenticated client may post a different user id (to see someone's else data? to post a message with someone's else name?). That said if you calculate that user ID from current logged in user then you don't really need to get it back from client. If it's something more complicated you should at least validate it against current logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a security risk, knowing the user's ID shouldn't be enough to get any confidential information. To get this information you have to make sure that user is authenticated, for example using authorize attribute and checking on the server side if the logged in user is allowed to perform current action.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the plain user id on the page for client side can lead to risk of hijacking . You need to authorize all the request for its capability to do the action as well as he is the person to do so. For example i have a profile page and now i change my User id in the page and update the First name , your code will not able to catch this hijacking because is authorized and he can update the profile. In case you want to keep the Id , generate the GUID all the time and keep it map to user id and GUID on the Server side. You can generate the GUID each time same user login . It will avoid the GUID hijacking because it is changed all the time.

You can keep this mapping in database for persistence and keep it in static variable or Cache in form of Dictionary for quicker mapping from GUID to user id.

```
     Dictionary<string,int> mapping = new Dictionary<string,int>;
```